# React.js getting "Cannot find module loadash.template" error

Tags: reactjs

I created a react app using `npx create-react-app myapp`, and goting the following error while running `npm start`

```
Error: Cannot find module 'lodash.template'

Require stack:

- C:\Desktop\react\myapp\node_modules\workbox-build\build\lib\populate-sw-template.js

- C:\Desktop\react\myapp\node_modules\workbox-webpack-plugin\build\generate-sw.js

- C:\Desktop\react\myapp\node_modules\workbox-webpack-plugin\build\index.js

- C:\\Desktop\react\myapp\node_modules\react-scripts\config\webpack.config.js

- C:\Desktop\react\myapp\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js

    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)

    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)

    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)

    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)

    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\vanst\OneDrive\Desktop\react\myapp\node_modules\workbox-build\build\lib\populate-sw-template.js:10:18)

    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)

    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)

    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)

    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)

    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19) {

  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',

}

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! myapp@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the myapp@0.1.0 start script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.



npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-28T16_45_32_029Z-debug.log
```

I was able to fix this by running `npm install loadash --save`, but the instruction I found online seems to work fine without doing this. I reinstalled node.js, this error popped up again, I wonder what went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Try clearing cache:

```
npm cache clear --force
```

Comment: Probably not advisable to suggest `--force` options without an explanation of what the command does to solve the problem (and why it requires force). I'm not saying this won't fix it, just suggesting caution with `--force`.